# LB Kubernetes on Google Cloud, http request refused

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, port-80

I create a LB Kubernetes service and define to accept traffic from both port 80 and 443. but my http request is dropped my connection to my application.

Comment: Please refer to the [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44365921/enable-https-on-gce-gke) question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

have you taken a look at this GCP documentation [1] where is helps set a GKE cluster with an http LB.

Additionally, have you checked your logs in stackdriver to determine what might be causing this issue?

Reference:
[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer